# Conditional Formatting by Expression using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting, epplus

I'm trying to format some range by using conditional Formatting feature of EPPlus. I read many document but there is nowhere mentions about Conditional Formatting Expression.

I'm very confusing. Don't know how to use that feature. Here are my some questions:

1. Can we use multiple range to put into parameter ExcelAddress (like
   "H1:H17,L1:L17,"AA1:AA17")
2. The formula is put into Formula property is somehow like Interop Excel or not? (like we use "A1" to represent for the current cell
   for formatting in interop excel)
3. Can you give me a small demo code leg that use Conditional Formatting Expression.

Thank you!

(Sorry for bad English I wrote)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have found out solution by myself. Please take an example code:

```
ExcelAddress _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("B3:B10,D3:D10,F3:F10,H3:H10:J3:J10");
// fill WHITE color if previous cell or current cell is BLANK:
// B3 is the current cell because the range _formatRangeAddress starts from B3.
// OFFSET(B3,0,-1) returns the previous cell's value. It's excel function.
string _statement = "IF(OR(ISBLANK(OFFSET(B3,0,-1)),ISBLANK(B3)),1,0)";
var _cond4 = sheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
_cond4.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
_cond4.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.White;
_cond4.Formula = _statement;

// fill GREEN color if value of the current cell is greater than 
//    or equals to value of the previous cell
_statement = "IF(OFFSET(B3,0,-1)-B3<=0,1,0)";
var _cond1 = sheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
_cond1.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
_cond1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Green;
_cond1.Formula = _statement;

// fill RED color if value of the current cell is less than 
//    value of the previous cell
_statement = "IF(OFFSET(B3,0,-1)-B3>0,1,0)";
var _cond3 = sheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
_cond3.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
_cond3.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Red;
_cond3.Formula = _statement;
```

In the above example,

- `_formatRangeAddress` is the range that will be applied for the
  conditional formatting by the expression. The first cell in this
  range will be used in the condition formula. (B3).
- `_statement` is
  the formula used to calculate the condition, this string **doesn't**
  start with equal sign (`=`) (difference point from MS Excel), the
  cell which is used to make expression is the first cell in the
  `_formatRangeAddress`. (B3).

Hope this is helpful to others who need. -Han-

Comment: can u provide for the "Contains" text conditional formatting

Comment: It is Excel function. I see that they use `ISNUMBER` and `SEARCH` funcions. http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/check-if-a-cell-contains-text-HP003056106.aspx

Comment: I want to use Conditional Formatting direct on Excel but I have no clear the `current` on your expression. You used as expression `IF(AND(ISBLANK(OFFSET(B3,0,-1)),ISBLANK(B3)),1,0)` and, in the code comment you says `// fill WHITE color if one of previous cell or current cell is BLANK:`. Where is the reference to `current` cell? I only see `B3`.

Comment: Hi. The `_formatRangeAddress` starts from `B3`, so in the formula, I use `B3`, It's current cell. Previous cell is `OFFSET(B3,0,-1)`. The comment seems not to be right. I'll correct the example statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is support for conditional formatting in the 3.1 beta version of EPPlus.

Take a look at the source-code here: http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/348196/

Comment: Actually this does not really focus on my question :(

Answer (score 0):

After many moons I found way more flexible and fast approach to do this using LINQ and EPPlus. All you need to do is: add extra property to your list to save Excel Row Numbers, and then retrieve cell addresses using LINQ. In this case it would look like this:

```
string sRng = string.Join(",", YourModel.Where(f => f.YourField == null)
    .Select(a => "H" + a.iRow + ",L" + a.iRow + ",AA" + a.iRow)); // this address could be many pages and it works

if (sRng.Length > 0) {
    ws.Cells[sRng].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Green); 
}
```

Here is the full article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1231992/Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel-with-LINQ-and-EPPl

Also see here another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022692/8216122
hope this helps somebody in the future.