# how to add conditional formatting on cells with values greater than a specific constant value using epplus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have made an excel sheet programmatically. and now I want to add conditional formatting on a specific cell range.

The formatting type is all the cells with `values greater than 0 (>0)`

How to go about doing it?
In excel I can do it using an inbuilt formula of `Cell Values Greater Than`. But how to embed it in excel using C# and epplus?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13196762/492

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i coudnt find an exact solution to this problem. so adding my own solution that works

```
var cellAddress = new ExcelAddress(
                        <startingRow>, 
                        <startingcolumn>, 
                        <endingRow>, 
                        <endingColumn>);

var cf = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddGreaterThan(cellAddress);
cf.Formula = "0";
cf.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.LightGreen;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I used: Formula = "ISBLANK("<startingRow><startingColumn>") // eg ISBLANK(C2)

Comment: you will also have to change the type of formulla in the line ws.ConditionalFormatting

Comment: Can't edit my comment for some reason... Yes I missed that part of your answer. I was using ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(cellAddress) with the ISBLANK formula.