# Format condition by expression EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, epplus

I am creating excel using EPPlus with conditional formatting. I am using C# code to do conditional formatting but its not working.

Please check my below code and let me know where I am wrong:

```
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample1");
var _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("H16:K31,H33:K44,H46:K57,H59:K69,H71:K73");
string _statement = "=AND(COUNTA(H16:H16)<2,COUNTA(H16:K16)>0)";
var _cond4 = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
_cond4.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
_cond4.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Green;
_cond4.Formula = _statement;
pck.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Sample1.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample1");
var _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("H16:K31,H33:K44,H46:K57,H59:K69,H71:K73");
string _statement = "AND(COUNTA(H16:H16)<2,COUNTA(H16:K16)>0)";
var _cond4 = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
_cond4.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
_cond4.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Green;
_cond4.Formula = _statement;
pck.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Sample1.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 7):

Set the formula string without the `=` at the beginning:

```
string _statement = "AND(COUNTA(H16:H16)<2,COUNTA(H16:K16)>0)";
[...]
_cond4.Formula = _statement;
```

The solution is mentioned here: [Conditional Formatting by Expression using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196762/conditional-formatting-by-expression-using-epplus)